# Return number of entries that have non-zero decimal places

Tags: r

Representative dataframe:

```
   X
   15.00
   12.01
   14.24
   4.00
   23.05
   67.00
```

I there a way I can use the sum() function to return the frequency of cells that have non-zero decimal places (i.e.: entries in X that are not whole numbers?).

In the above examples, this would be 3 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
sum(df$X %% 1 != 0, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(15, 12.01, 14.24, 4, 23.05, 67)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: You may have `NA` values in your data, use `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum`. I have updated the answer.